# simpleMembership with asp.net mvc 4 and .net Framework 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, simplemembership

I've been stack for 4 days into trying to use simplemembership with my own database.

I'm using visual studio 2012 and .net Framework 4.

I used the internet application template for asp.net mvc 4, that has already built in login.

First I created a database based on an ADO.net entity data model.
I added one table : UsersTableSet to the database. that has Id, UserName and Password.

I got this connection string when I created the database based on the model:

```
<add name="UsersDBContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/UsersDB.csdl|res://*/UsersDB.ssdl|res://*/UsersDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MAZEN\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=USERSDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Then, I went to filter and modified this :

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("UsersDBContainer", "UsersTableSet", "Id", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

But when I run the application and go to login I get this error:

```
The data provider. Net Framework requested was not found. It may not be installed.
```

I'm really confused, I searched a lot in the internet and this error doesn't seem to be specific to the simplemembership.

What else do I need to change.
In some articles I read that simplemembership can't work if there are 2 DBContext?
Do I need to delete the AccountModels.cs and starts a new one?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<add name="UsersDBContainer" connectionString="Data Source=MAZEN\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=USERSDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Try above, it's how my connection string would look like